# Vaadin Flow rerouting in HasUrlParameter#setParameter does not change URL?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

My login view with `@Route("login")` implements `HasUrlParameter<String>` with the following lines:

```
@Override
public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, @WildcardParameter String parameter) {
    event.rerouteTo(AnotherView.class);
}
```

The content of the `AnotherView` is shown when I call the login view but the URL remains from the login view, i.e. it is */login* instead of */another-view*. Is that works-as-designed? I would expect a history entry to be added in the browser with the new URL. How can I achieve that? Also, I tried `ui.navigateTo` instead of rerouting but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is known on github project of Vaadin flow: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4189.